# Woocommerce - Missing Account Details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

As the Title suggests, I made an e-Commerce web application with Woocommerce plugin, but now I cannot access My Account details Page (Edit details, retrieve lost password). I have tried going to

- Woocommerce
- System Status
- Install missing Pages

but this too didn't resolve my problem. I have tried deleting the page, and create it again, yet it still missing.

The Error I received when I want to edit my account detail is

> No posts found

I did modified my Posts and Pages by adding some wp_editor, but I never change anything from the woocommerce's my Account detail section.

Anyone have this kind of problem? Reinstalling the Woocommerce is not an option since I've gone too far, and I'm afraid reinstalling could mess everything..

Woocommerce Version : 2.3.6
WP Version : 4.1.8

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new page.
2. Add the correct page shortcode.
   3.Publish.
3. Go to: **WooCommerce > Settings > *tab*** to select your newly created page (*tab* defines the WooCommerce section to edit) if you use WooCommerce > 2.1.x, else go to **WooCommerce > Settings > General**.
4. Save.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast reply

I have followed your instruction but it still show no post found. I' using the shortcode [code][woocommerce_my_account][/code] from [link]https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/[/link] Any other idea?